# Kusto select distinct on one column only

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Example Query -

traces
| project message, timestamp

This outputs something like this -

```
message  |   timestamp
------------------------------
    A      2022-07-09 00:00:00
    B      2022-07-11 01:00:00
    A      2022-07-11 02:00:00
```

I want a query that gives this as output -

```
message  |   timestamp
------------------------------
    A      2022-07-09 00:00:00
    B      2022-07-11 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the `min()` aggregation function if you only have 2 fields of interest (`message`, `timestamp`), or the `arg_min()` aggregation function otherwise.

e.g.

```
traces | summarize min(timestamp) by message

traces | summarize arg_min(timestamp, *) by message
```